# Creating a Netezza UDX from TSQL

Tags: function, stored-procedures, netezza

I am an enzee newbie and need help to convert a MSSQL function we wrote to the new Netezza appliance. I do not know C++, so any help will be appreciated.  Here is the sql code:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[PMT] 
(
      -- Add the parameters for the function here
      @Term float,
      @Rate float,
      @LoanSize float
)
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN
      -- Declare the return variable here
      DECLARE @Result float
      DECLARE @NewRate float

      set @NewRate = @Rate/1200
      -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
      SELECT @Result =
      case when @NewRate = 0 then 
            @LoanSize/@Term 
      else
            @LoanSize/((1-(1/POWER(1+@NewRate,@Term)))/(@NewRate))
      end

      -- Return the result of the function
      RETURN @Result

END
```

Comment: Your question dosen;t prove the purpose of C++ UDF, because this is just a database procedure which you can write in same way in Netezza as well. Please elaborate if something more required.

Answer (score 0):

Queries can't be done in a UDF. Everything that you pass to the UDF is performed on every row. If the UDF is deterministic is will return one answer per row. I don't see anything in this that should require a UDF though

```
select somenum as newrate, somename as term, somenum as loansize,
case 
when NewRate = 0 
     then LoanSize/Term 
     else LoanSize/((1-(1/POWER(1+NewRate,Term)))/(NewRate))
end as mynewcol
```